# How to install Docker in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

While installing Docker Desktop using the command in Ubuntu `sudo apt-get install ./docker-desktop-<version>-<arch>.deb` I'm getting `bash: version: No such file or directory' error.`

The log is -
`sudo apt-get install ./docker-desktop-<version>-<arch>.deb`

```
Hit:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease                 
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                      
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]
Fetched 324 kB in 2s (139 kB/s)     
Reading package lists... Done
bash: version: No such file or directory

But the Docker Engine has been configured successfully.

Running docker --version I am getting 
Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086
```

Comment: is docker actually working? anyway question such as this is off-topic here

Answer (score 2):

When you read the page at https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/ubuntu/ and it says

`sudo apt-get install ./docker-desktop-<version>-<arch>.deb`

it actually means that you should insert *the current values* for the *placeholders* that are `<version>` and `<arch>`. This could be something like `20.10.16~3` and `amd64`, it will depend on what is in their repo at the time.

The error you got from `bash`, namely `bash: version: No such file or directory' error` is a side-effect of the `<` and `>` having special meaning to `bash` so it saw a redirect.  The error was local to your computer though.

Comment: I passed the version as ```5:20.10.13~3-0~ubuntu-jammy-docker-desktop-4.11.1``` and arch as ```docker-desktop-4.11.1-amd64.deb``` and now I'm getting an error ```E: Unsupported file ./docker-desktop-5:20.10.13~3-0~ubuntu-jammy-docker-desktop-4.11.1-amd64.deb given on commandline```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the apt:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg \
    lsb-release

sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg

echo \
  "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
```

Full instruction: [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/)